# How can I get genrule's output directory even it as an external?

Tags: bazel

I want extend cc_library for some reason, one thing I need todo it's get a genrule's output directory, I known can use GENDIR variable, but target if was depended as an external will made this wrong. here is an example:

https://github.com/xiedeacc/libdwarf.git

BUILD

```
genrule(
    name = "config_h",
    outs = ["config.h"],
    cmd = "\n".join([
        "cat <<'EOF' >$@",
        "balabal",
        "EOF",
    ]),
)
cc_library(
    name = "dwarf",
    srcs = glob(["src/lib/libdwarf/*.c"]),
    hdrs = ["config.h"] + glob(["src/lib/libdwarf/*.h"]),
    copts = [
        "-g",
        "-O2",
        "-march=native",
    ],
    includes = [
        "src/lib/libdwarf",
    ],
    local_defines = [
        "HAVE_CONFIG_H",
        "LIBDWARF_BUILD",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@com_github_facebook_zstd//:libzstd",
        "@zlib",
    ],
)
```

cc_library.bzl

```
def cc_library_impl(attrs):
    config_h_path = function_or_variable_that_get_config_h_path()
    if "copts" in attrs and attrs["cotps"] != None:
        attrs["copts"] = attrs["copts"] + [config_h_path]
    else:
        attrs["copts"] = [config_h_path]
    return attrs

def cc_library(**attrs):
    native.cc_library(**cc_library_impl(attrs))
```